# Large-format Vinyl for Decals or Labels

Tags: print-design, print-production, color-reproduction, vinyl, ink

What's the best large-format vinyl to print on using eco-solvent inks? Vinyl for decals or labels? I'm currently running a Roland SOLJET PRO4 XR-640.

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: What do you mean by "best"? What are you looking to accomplish?

Comment: We print numerous labels for government GFE where I work. I was looking for suggestions from other printers about their "go to" vinyl for simple product labels.